# Get the output in a formatted way

Tags: text-processing, echo, printf, text-formatting

In a `for` loop, I am using the command:

```
echo " Job_time is $i : Stopping the job "
```

Sample output:

```
Job_time is 6 : Stopping the job
Job_time is 6.50 : Stopping the job
```

Desired output:

```
Job_time is 6    : Stopping the job
Job_time is 6.50 : Stopping the job
```

Comment: Please correct the appearance of your desired output.

Comment: one word: printf

Comment: @cas, you should write that as an answer!

Comment: @JamesYoungman - feel free to steal my comment and turn it into an answer.  i'll upvote it if it's good. comments are free for the taking :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `echo`, you can use `printf` for specifying the width of some field.  For the given example, replace

```
echo " Job_time is $i : Stopping the job "
```

with

```
printf ' Job_time is %-4s : Stopping the job \n' "$i"
```

since `$i` is apparently a string with different lengths.  If it is always a valid floating-point number, you could use a numeric format and make `printf` show trailing zeros:

```
printf ' Job_time is %4.2f : Stopping the job \n' "$i"
```

e.g.,

```
Job_time is 6.00 : Stopping the job
Job_time is 6.50 : Stopping the job
```

Further reading:

- [The printf command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) (bash wiki)
- [printf - write formatted output](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (POSIX)

Answer (score -1):

Always print `stopping the job` beginning at column 14

```sh
for ((i=0; i<100; i++))
do
    local offset=14
    printf "%s%*s\n" "Job_time is $i" $offset ": Stopping the job"

done
```